Too low baseline with italics in comments
I noticed that some of the italicized words in comments are too low, on at least one site. See I pronounce question as kweshtin. Is my pronunciation wrong? and also the following screenshot:

Comment markdown:
*Test* [Test *comment*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429562) comment Also see *[Is “question” pronounced with an “s” or with an “sh” sound?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286932/)* and *[How to pronounce “Question”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429562)*

It doesn't happen all the time (for example, the first word in my example isn't affected and it also doesn't seem to happen in short messages).
Browser: iOS Chrome, Safari (narrow mode only)

On what browser? Have you tried any other browser? What operating system? What browser version?

@AaronBertrand Can you try in narrow mode (search bar/rep hidden)? As soon as I do landscape (search bar/rep shown), the problem disappears.
